# How to remove redundant casts in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I was targeting SDK version 21 or 22 in one or my old projects.But now I have updated to the latest SDK version. Now I can see a lot of redundant casts of views (As view casts are redundant now). Is there any alternate to remove all those redundant casts at once Via any short cut way rather going through each and every file and remove? I am using Android Studio version 3.2 now.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing **ctrl+shft+A** will open action dialog. In it type **clean** in and from suggestion list select **Code Cleanup**. This will open a separate dialog from which you  can select your relative scope. Select which option suits your need and press **OK**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on directory which you want clean up.
- Select Analyze > Code Cleanup
- Click OK.

Here you go!

Answer (score 0):

- Select Your Project folder or app (according to your project explorer view)
- Select `Analyze` from **menubar**
- choose option `Code cleanup` or `silent code cleanup` .

  Where Code cleanup prompt you dialog with options like Project or module and silent code cleanup cleanup without displaying the Code Cleanup dialog. from currently selected project or module.

Comment: what is the difference between your and below mentioned answer?

Comment: silent code clean up will not prompt confirmation dialog whether you want to code cleanup or not and it will also no provide you options like whole project or selective module